# Find the general solution for $y' + ky = e^{-kx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution for $y' + ky = e^{-kx}$

Here's what I have tried:

Using the equation for a nonhomegenous linear ODE where $r(x)$ is not everywhere zero.

$$y(x) = e^{-h}\left(\int e^hrdx+c \right)$$

I started by showing that

$h = \int k dx \implies e^h = e^{kx} \implies e^{-h} = e^{-kx}$

Then solving for $e^hr = e^{-kx}\cdot e^{kx}=1$

Result:
$$e^{-kx}\left(\int e^{kx}dx+c \right)=Ce^{-kx}+1$$

However, the answer in the book is $(x+c)e^{-kx}$, how was this derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula you have, just that you have made a mistake: indeed
$$y(x) = e^{-h}\left(\int e^hrdx+c \right) = e^{-x} \left( \int 1 dx + c\right)=e^{-kx} (x+c)$$

(The mistake you made is that you put the wrong term $e^{kx}$ instead of $re^h = 1$ inside the integral)

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying both side by $e^{kx}$, then we get $e^{kx}y'+ke^{kx}y=1$. It is, $\frac d{dx}(e^{kx}y)=1$.

Then integrating this, we can get $e^{kx}y=x+C$, so $y=(x+C)e^{-kx}$.

Comment: Is there a name to this method?